# Problem with baseDN on Active directory LDAP, cant find the object

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have the following tree hierarchy in active directory for LDAP server

- domain (example.net)

  - dir1
  - dir2
  - Users

    - user1
    - group1
    - user2
    - group2
  - dir3
    ...

During anonymous_logon, when i use full baseDN to Users directory as (CN=Users, DC=example, DC=net) i receive an error
SearchResult(resultCode=32 (no such object), messageID=5, diagnosticMessage=’0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031529DD, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT) and as a result cant login under the user1 credentials to my application.
But when i use cropped baseDN such as (DC=example, DC=net) i can login under the mentioned user. What can be wrong with settings on LDAP server or somewhere else?
Moreover, if i use (CN=group1, CN=Users, DC=example, DC=net) as baseDN connection is also passed. So i assume problem is in the Users directory settings.

Also for anonymous_logon group i switched on the rights to be applied to this object and all descendants objects.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on the code side, i reverted last commit and started to work. I'm closing this question.